# C# MVC 5 EF 6 - Suddenly Views on "Create" controller methods are causing null exceptions on EditorFor methods

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using Visual Studio 2019; 16.8.6

I've been developing this solution for a few days now.  Suddenly, started getting null exceptions on all my "create" forms.

Please do NOT link me to general questions about what null exceptions are and how to debug them.  This is NOT that simple.

I'm using the scaffolding in VS2019 to initially create all my controllers and views.  The following is basically straight from the scaffolding and how I've built MVC solutions for the last 6 or so years.

from the "UsersController.cs":

```
        // GET: Users/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Don't tell me returning View() without passing an "empty object" isn't normal.  That's How I've always done it.  That's how the scaffolding built it.  That's how it worked just fine in this same solution for days until it suddenly didn't anymore.

Top lines of my "\Views\Users\Create.cshtml"

```
@model Howsyomamanem2.Models.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<div class="container">
    <h1>Create</h1>

    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>User</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.UserId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

The null exception occcurs on the @Html.EditFor... and on every "field" following that in the view.

The exact message reads:  "System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'"

This seems to have started happening right after the 1st "Publish" to my web server.  I'm wondering if my solution/project has been corrupted or if normally these exceptions happen except there's some setting in the MVC framework that normally ignores them has been turned off.

I've searched high and low for help with this specific issue and none that I've found fit this specific problem.  Any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

I'd also like to point out that it's not generating exceptions when published to the server only in my local debug environment

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this issue while trying to correct the browser linkage between VS and Edge/Chrome.  When I turned off the "Just My Code" in Tools/Options/Debugging/General I started getting this error.  When I turned the option back on the issue went away.
[image: Copy of Options Window]

Answer (score 0):

Answer:   The best I can tell, some configuration was altered in VS2019 that was causing these exceptions to happen suddenly.  **The fix:**  I did a repair install of VS2019 and the issue is gone.

I hope this helps someone in the future...

Sincerest thanks to all the Stackoverflow community for all the replies and helpful tips.

Answer (score 0):

This drove me absolutely insane because, as you said, the code is generated by VS MVC+EF!

The fix for me was to check the 2nd box on the exception tooltip:
"Except for System.Web.Mvc"